# Geocoding Guam addresses with their latitude/longuitude?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geocoding, united-states

I am attempting to get lat/longs for a table of 25,000 addresses for Guam. Guam's addressing style doesn't follow the typical address number range. I've exhausted all of my geocoding resources. ESRI, Google, Bing, Yahoo, HERE, and various educational facilities. Google, thus far, has been most promising, but I am only get street centerline values returned.

I was curious whether anyone out there had attempted this before, and if anyone had any resources/ideas about how I can go about this.

Using ArcGIS 10.2 Advanced

Sample Addresses:

```
103 Ciriaco Loop, 96910-2070
143 Taluba Rd, 96910-2078
176 Chorito Blvd, 96910-1600
310 Ladera Ln, 96913-5868
141 Jolene Leon Guerrero St, 96913-1324
```

Comment: Please add a sample of the addresses you are trying to geocode.  Giving any additional information you know about the structure of the dataset is going to increase the likelihood that someone can help you.  Also, do you have access to a street centerline file for Guam to use to geocode against?  This would enable you to set up some sort of custom geocoder in ArcGIS.

Comment: LeadDog has GIS data for Guam and it is good for Geocoding Addresses in Guam. It is a commercial product (not free) http://goleaddog.com/gis-map/asia/guam/

Comment: I downloaded the TIGER streets for Guam, they do not have left/right from/to address ranges, because Guam doesn't follow that standard. The ADDRFEAT files are not available for Guam, those are what I used to build my other locators.

Comment: At the moment I think this Question is too broad.  Based on the Comments so far, would you be able to revise it with where you are now up to with finding a solution, please?  If you do not have one then can you perhaps refine what you are looking for.  From my reading it sounds like you do not care how they are geocoded, or whether that geocoding is free, but then it sounds like you are wanting to perform desktop geocoding, and more interested in learning a technique that works for Guam.